# sum of the alternating harmonic series but every third term removed

Tags: summation, divergent-series

$$ X = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i} = \log 2$$

If we just look at the series formed from the third terms of the alternating harmonic series, we get

$$Y = -\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{12} +... $$
$$ = -\frac{1}{3} (1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - ...) = -\frac{\log 2}{3}$$

So one would think that the sum of the series in question is

$$ X - Y = \frac{4}{3}\log 2 = 0.9241962407465937$$

But numerical evaluation gives me one fourth of that $0.2310485601873915$.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Geez, you just made a sign error! Look at the term in the sum when $i=3$.

Comment: Great catch. But now the answer would be $2/3 \log 2$ which is ~0.46. The answer i think is $1/3 \log 2$. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I made a mistake in the numerical calc also and the answer is indeed $(2/3) \log 2$. Thanks

Comment: I just wanted to post the same: gp tells me that the numerical result is in very good agreement with the theoretical one.